# ehcache 3 cache-through with spring boot and JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ehcache

- spring boot version: 1.4.1.RELEASE
- ehcache version: 3.1.3
- OS: mac 10.11.6
- java: 1.8.0_91

I followed along w/ ["Caching 101" with Louis Jacomet & Aurelien Broszniowski](https://youtu.be/FQfd8x29Ud8) to get my feet wet with cache-through using ehcache 3.

There are a few things this presentation glazes over (but mentions briefly). One of them is cache key management, which now becomes the application's responsibility; since the objects/data created are cached 1st b/f they are persisted (the whole point of cache-through) we don't have available to us the db-generated 'id' which is returned (JPA) ... we have to add a new field to the Entity to store this cache key.

So, I created a 'key generator' that maintains a Set of Long, cache keys. Fine. But, when the application stops, this Set goes away. So, if there were any objects/entries created while the application was running & persisted in the db, on startup, these records need to be inserted into the application cache AND the cache key (Set) needs to be populated as well.

[In my sample code](https://github.com/maspen/boot-1.4.1-ehcache-3-h2-cache-through), my rest controller is the one who interacts w/ the cache and I added a method to accomplish this. It calls repository.findAll() to populate a List of entities (Product in this case). Since each, previously-persisted entity also persisted the cache key, I iterate through this list & populate the cache; or so I think.

```
    @PostConstruct
        private void initializeCacheFromDB() {
    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    repository.findAll().forEach(productList::add);

    for (Product product : productList) {
        // update the cache
        // NOTE: below has no effect!
        productCache.put(product.getCacheKey(), product);
        // update/set the keys
        CustomKeyGenerator.addKey(product.getCacheKey());
    }

    // does nothing!!!! ... no entries so keys not associated w/ Product(s)
    //productCache.getAll(CustomKeyGenerator.getKeysSet());

    System.out.println("done w/ initializeCacheFromDB()");
}
```

But, when, after the console confirms that the app. has started, I navigate to a rest endpoint to get said list, its empty!

So, my question is, how to populate the cache on startup with any persisted data.

Answer (score 0):

Use  BootstrapCacheLoader
See http://www.ehcache.org/documentation